# Facebook login crashes on IPv6 network

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, ipv6

In my app I have implemented login with Facebook, like this:

```
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
    #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:vc handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

But when I push this code to ItunesConnect I get the following reject:

> Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 connected to an
>   IPv6 network when we:
>
> - Crashes when trying to use Facebook as a means to login.

Is there a way to use the Facebook login and still support IPv6 network?

Comment: That message doesn't mean the ipv6 network is the cause of the crash, they are just saying they happened to be testing on an ipv6 network when it crashed.  You need to look at the crash report they send you to find the actual reason for the crash.

Comment: This post can help you to test your app in ipv6 network: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

Comment: @dan you are right! The problem was actually connected to asking for Keychain permissions.